# vim: delete all lines but unique?

Tags: vim, macros, gvim

I am looking for a way in VIM to delete all lines that are duplicates and only leave unique lines that exist in the file.  I would prefer a macro but a command or function would be great.

Say I have a file that has duplicate lines and some uniques:

```
1Apple
1Apple
2Peach
2Peach
2Peach
3Beer
4Banana
4Banana
4Banana
```

I want to delete all lines so that all that is left:

```
3Beer
```

The one unique line that I REALLY want.

I use sort u all the time to get a unique list by deleting duplicates but I have times I just need the unique line in the file.

Any ideas how to handle this case in VIM?

Comment: Use the right tool to do this type of work....use uniq which is used for this type of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the substitute command and a backreference:

```
s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+//
```

Note that this only works if the lines are sorted. This works by matching and removing the first group one or more times on the next line(s).

Comment: Since I do not have Uniq, I did a macro in VIM to loop over and delete non uniques.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the "uniq" command to do this -

```
uniq -u filename-to-check.txt
```

Comment: and you could even run it as a filter inside Vim ... would be cool if your answer would contain *that* ...

Comment: `:%!sort | uniq -u` will do just that: sort, remove all lines that are not unique, and leave the result in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke the `uniq` tool as a filter directly from Vim:

```
:!%uniq -u
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all the lines you want to filter.
2. Do `:'<,'>!uniq -u<CR>`, the `'<,'>` range is added automatically for you.

If you want to filter the whole buffer, don't select anything and simply do `:%!uniq -u<CR>`.

You can read about filters in `:h filter`.

Comment: I take it uniq is not an option in windows 7?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe with something like Cygwin? You should have indicated that. All the answers here are useless if you don't have uniq on your machine.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned windows.  That was one reason I asked about a macro to try and keep it in vim.   I was able to write a macro around the recommended s/^\(.*\)\(\n\1\)\+// and it worked ok for 50k lines.